# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need some help with an issue that I don't know how to solve.
It's a code that I wrote for a web scraping. I created an executable file and when I run it, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Robo Ajuste Norber.py", line 77, in <module>

File "webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 39, in install

File "webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 30, in _get_driver_path

File "webdriver_manager\core\download_manager.py", line 28, in download_file

File "webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 39, in get

File "webdriver_manager\core\utils.py", line 264, in show_download_progress

File "tqdm\std.py", line 1095, in __init__

File "tqdm\std.py", line 1344, in refresh

File "tqdm\std.py", line 1492, in display

File "tqdm\std.py", line 347, in print_status

File "tqdm\std.py", line 340, in fp_write

File "tqdm\utils.py", line 71, in __getattr__

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

The code runs perfectly, but the executable file doesn't work.

Here's what's written in the lines 76-80.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same situation and managed to resolve it. Here is what I did:

Go to the utils.py:
`your_python_path\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\utils.py`

Locate line 383, which corresponds to the show_download_progress function.

```
def show_download_progress(response, _bytes_threshold=100):
    return
    skip following...
```

Add the line return at the beginning of the function. This prevents the execution of the error section.

I guess the reason for this error is likely that there is no way to output the progress bar, causing the issue.